# ¿How replace and insert new node?

Tags: xquery, executable-jar

Well, I have this xml file executed in a jar file and I want to add a new field and update another, the problem arises when adding a new one comes out as correct but nothing is flattened and when updating the data, I don't stop getting an error that I have the wrong fields,

Here the code
xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type ="text/xsl" href = "ejercicio2parte1.xslt"?>
<musica>
    <cd>
        <titulo_del_album>Los magroños</titulo_del_album>
        <artista>Julian</artista>
            <cancion>
                <nombre>El cairo</nombre>
                <duracion>4.50s</duracion>
            </cancion>
        <sello_discografico>sony BGM</sello_discografico>
        <anyo_de_publicacion>1996</anyo_de_publicacion>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <titulo_del_album>Scarecrow</titulo_del_album>
        <artista>Avantasia</artista>
            <cancion>
                <nombre>Scarecrow</nombre>
                <duracion>7.11</duracion>
            </cancion>
        <sello_discografico>sony BGM</sello_discografico>
        <anyo_de_publicacion>1999</anyo_de_publicacion>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <titulo_del_album>Chichos</titulo_del_album>
        <artista>Jacobo</artista>
            <cancion>
                <nombre>El rapido</nombre>
                <duracion>1.50</duracion>
            </cancion>
        <sello_discografico>El oro</sello_discografico>
        <anyo_de_publicacion>1995</anyo_de_publicacion>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <titulo_del_album>Los rocos</titulo_del_album>
        <artista>Martin</artista>
            <cancion>
                <nombre>Fulda</nombre>
                <duracion>5.00</duracion>
            </cancion>
        <sello_discografico>El oro</sello_discografico>
        <anyo_de_publicacion>2018</anyo_de_publicacion>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <titulo_del_album>Jacobinos</titulo_del_album>
        <artista>El caucho</artista>
            <cancion>
                <nombre>French</nombre>
                <duracion>6.20</duracion>
            </cancion>
        <sello_discografico>AFM Records</sello_discografico>
        <anyo_de_publicacion>2010</anyo_de_publicacion>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <titulo_del_album>JOJO</titulo_del_album>
        <artista>Dio</artista>
            <cancion>
                <nombre>Kono dio da</nombre>
                <duracion>1.00</duracion>
            </cancion>
        <sello_discografico>JOJO Bizarre</sello_discografico>
        <anyo_de_publicacion>2000</anyo_de_publicacion>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <titulo_del_album>Black beast</titulo_del_album>
        <artista>Beast in Blakc</artista>
            <cancion>
                <nombre>Berserker</nombre>
                <duracion>5.49</duracion>
            </cancion>
        <sello_discografico>Nuclear Blast Records</sello_discografico>
        <anyo_de_publicacion>2009</anyo_de_publicacion>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <titulo_del_album>K/DA</titulo_del_album>
        <artista>Akali</artista>
            <cancion>
                <nombre>ALL OUT</nombre>
                <duracion>5.00</duracion>
            </cancion>
        <sello_discografico>Nuclear Blast Records</sello_discografico>
        <anyo_de_publicacion>2019</anyo_de_publicacion>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <titulo_del_album>Plentakill</titulo_del_album>
        <artista>Mordekaiser</artista>
            <cancion>
                <nombre>Thornamill</nombre>
                <duracion>4.30</duracion>
            </cancion>
        <sello_discografico>Nuclear Blast Records</sello_discografico>
        <anyo_de_publicacion>2016</anyo_de_publicacion>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <titulo_del_album>Moonglow</titulo_del_album>
        <artista>The thunder</artista>
            <cancion>
                <nombre>Cosmic night</nombre>
                <duracion>6.00</duracion>
            </cancion>
        <sello_discografico>Nuclear Blast Records</sello_discografico>
        <anyo_de_publicacion>2004</anyo_de_publicacion>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <titulo_del_album>Mistery of time</titulo_del_album>
        <artista>Edguy</artista>
            <cancion>
                <nombre>Deep purple</nombre>
                <duracion>5.40</duracion>
            </cancion>
        <sello_discografico>Nuclear Blast Records</sello_discografico>
        <anyo_de_publicacion>2019</anyo_de_publicacion>
    </cd>
</musica>
```

Her the code of my insert:

```
insert node
<cd>
        <titulo_del_album>dsadsaw</titulo_del_album>
        <artista>asddsasa</artista>
            <cancion>
                <nombre>asdsada</nombre>
                <duracion>7.11</duracion>
            </cancion>
        <sello_discografico>sony BGM</sello_discografico>
        <anyo_de_publicacion>1999</anyo_de_publicacion>
    </cd>


before doc("Ejercicio2.xml") //musica
```

And my code of update:

```
replace value of node
//cd/artista=("Julian")/cancion/nombre
with "Gloria Fuertes"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `insert` expression, you are telling the XQuery engine to insert the `<cd>` node before `//musica`. However, `<musica>` is the root node of the document, so inserting a node before it would cause the XML file to be non-well-formed. I would expect the engine to throw an error.

If your goal is to insert the `<cd>` element into the `<musica>` element, you would use the following expression:

```
insert node <cd/> into doc("Ejercicio2.xml")/musica
```

To control whether the element is inserted as the first element or the last element, add `as first` or `as last` before the `into` keyword.

For the `replace` expression, you have a syntax error where you try to select the `<artista>` element, and your path to the `<nombre>` element is wrong.

To select the Julian `<artista>` element, use a filter expression:

```
//cd/artista[. = "Julian"]
```

Extending this to find the `<nombre>` element:

```
//cd[artista = "Julian"]/cancion/nombre
```

Note that, despite the indentation of your sample XML file, `<cancion>` is not a child element of `<artista>` - but rather is its sibling.